# Trying to create custom disk metric published by CW unified agent for multiple instances in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Scenario - if There are multiple ebs volumes attached to an instance metric_name= "disk_used_percent" will be published for each device I want to loop through successfully so can create alarms for each device and have a name with the proper instance ID in it.
Github - https://github.com/hirenshah005/cloudwatch

```
data "aws_instance" "x" {
count       = "${length(data.aws_instances.all_ec2.ids)}"
instance_id = "${element(data.aws_instances.all_ec2.*.id, count.index)}"
}

#------------Disk Alarms------------------
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "disk_used_percent" {
count                     = "${length(data.aws_instance.x.*.ebs_block_device)}"
alarm_name                = "Disk_used_percent_below_10%_on-${data.aws_instance.x.id}-${element(data.aws_instance.x.ebs_block_device.device_name, count.index)}"
comparison_operator       = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
evaluation_periods        = "2"
datapoints_to_alarm       = "2"
metric_name               = "disk_used_percent"
namespace                 = "Custim/CWAgent"
period                    = "900"
threshold                 = "10"
insufficient_data_actions = []

dimensions {
InstanceId = "${element(data.aws_instances.all_ec2.ids, count.index)}"
}

alarm_description = "This alarm will trigger when usable EBS storage is below 10% on --> ${data.aws_instances.all_ec2.ids[count.index]}"
alarm_actions     = ["${var.sns_notification_arn}"]
}
```

Error----------

```
data.aws_instances.all_ec2: Refreshing state...
data.aws_instance.x[0]: Refreshing state...
data.aws_instance.x[2]: Refreshing state...
data.aws_instance.x[4]: Refreshing state...
data.aws_instance.x[1]: Refreshing state...
data.aws_instance.x[3]: Refreshing state...

Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x: 5 error(s) occurred:

* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x[1]: data.aws_instance.x.1: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "terraform-20181129025105352600000001"
        status code: 400, request id: 11c44ab9-06c0-466c-9d08-2e5cafcedb9a
* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x[0]: data.aws_instance.x.0: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "terraform-20181129025105352600000001"
        status code: 400, request id: 072d11e8-9067-41e2-a79b-6a4f09b5af07
* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x[3]: data.aws_instance.x.3: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "terraform-20181129025105352600000001"
        status code: 400, request id: 7a59d224-36bf-44be-ac17-ee8b65e6a6c5
* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x[4]: data.aws_instance.x.4: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "terraform-20181129025105352600000001"
        status code: 400, request id: 6ca1bfed-d38b-4868-86e5-bc042085ff90
* module.cloudwatch-metrics.data.aws_instance.x[2]: data.aws_instance.x.2: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "terraform-20181129025105352600000001"
        status code: 400, request id: f1dd970e-5faa-4c20-ae0f-00869e3bcdae
```

Comment: Hello @Hiren - Have you tried this code? What errors do you get?

Comment: Yes I have tried this and not working as per my need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your scenario properly, unfortunately, I don't believe this is currently possible with Terraform v0.11.x.

Here's why: you have a variable # of instances with a variable # of EBS volumes attached. e.g. instance #1 has 2 EBS vols, instance #2 has 3, instance #3 has 1, etc.

The `count` on the `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` has to be the *sum* of the # of EBS volumes. In v0.11.x, there isn't a more sophisticated loop other than `count`.

Now if the # of volumes attached to each instance is fixed, then you could perform a multiplication calculation to determine the count. *--> If this is true, update your question and I'll update this answer.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Terraform 0.12 and above [using the multiple alarms module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudwatch#metric-alarms-by-multiple-dimensions)

Basically you can specify multiple dimensions with the same alarm conditions and it'll create the necessary alarms for you